# Submitting form doesn't work after using Recaptcha v3

Tags: laravel, forms, recaptcha

I'm trying to use Recaptcha v3 on my form but submitting the form only works when Recaptcha is removed.
When Recaptcha is enabled, I can click on the submit button but nothing happens. I don't even get an error message in the console even though I can see the **protected by reCAPTCHA** logo in the frontend on the bottom right.
I'm using Laravel 6.

My form template looks like this:

```
    <div class="row mt-150">
    <div class="col-12 text-center text-white">
        <h1>Contact</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
        <form action="{{route('contact_form')}}" method="POST">
            @csrf
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email" class="text-white">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="textarea" class="text-white">Message</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="textarea" rows="3" name="message" required></textarea>
            </div>
            <input type="submit"
                    id="submitButton"
                    class="g-recaptcha btn btn-primary"
                    data-sitekey="MY-PUBLIC-KEY"
                    data-callback='onSubmit'
                    data-action='submit'
                    name="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
```

There is also an app.js included which contains the captcha callback function:

```
function onSubmit(token) {
  document.getElementById("submitButton").submit();
}
window.onSubmit = onSubmit;
```

Can someone give me a hint what I'm doing wrong implementing recaptcha?
I tried to do it just like this:

[Google reCaptcha v3](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3#automatically_bind_the_challenge_to_a_button)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will not work because you are trying to trigger `submit()` on a button. Give the form an id and then trigger `submit()` on the form

```html
<form action="{{route('contact_form')}}" method="POST" id="contactForm">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email" class="text-white">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="textarea" class="text-white">Message</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="textarea" rows="3" name="message" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit"
        id="submitButton"
        class="g-recaptcha btn btn-primary"
        data-sitekey="MY-PUBLIC-KEY"
        data-callback='onSubmit'
        data-action='submit'
        name="submit">
</form>
```

Then in javascript get the form and trigger submit on it

```js
function onSubmit(token) {
  document.getElementById("contactForm").submit();
}
window.onSubmit = onSubmit;
```

Comment: After your approach it didn't work the first time. I also had to remove the name="submit" attribute from the submit button in order to make it work. With these two small changes submitting the form works again. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @UmutSavas you could turn this into an answer ?

Comment: @UmutSavas after an hour of going crazy figuring out why it didn't work, your suggestion to remove the name = 'submit' worked!!!. But I don't know whats the relation with it.